# Using a cursor in another procedure of same package

Tags: plsql

Can we use a cursor declared in one procedure of the package in another procedure of the same package?

Answer (score 2):

No, like anything declared inside a procedure it is local to that procedure.  However you can declare a cursor at the package level and use it in both procedures.

```
package body my_pkg is

   cursor emp_cur is select * from emp;

   procedure p1 is 
   begin
      open emp_cur;
      ...
      close emp_cur;
   end p1;

   procedure p2 is 
   begin
      open emp_cur;
      ...
      close emp_cur;
   end p2;
end;
```

Note though that if procedure p1 opens emp_cur but doesn't close it, then if p2 tries to open it it will get an exception.